# Ruby on rails - production mode, not serving files under sub directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby on rails app, I have a data folder inside the public folder and this data folder contains subfolders. The data is well displayed (visually) in the browser in development mode, but in production mode it only displays the data inside the folder but not the data inside the subfolders. For example: it would display public/data/sample.json but it does not display public/data/folder/sample.json.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your production environment hosted? Perhaps Heroku?

Comment: no. I am using passenger + nginx. I am hosting my own server.